# "Get-Help $PSCommandPath -Examples" does not show examples, if run after "Get-Help $PSCommandPath" inside a script

Tags: powershell

I'm not sure if this is a bug or whether I'm just doing something dumb. The Powershell script below is reduced as much as possible out of a larger script. Running the commands (with strings, not variables) one after another in Powershell works fine. It's just the script doesn't do what I want.

**What I want to do:**

I want to show the default help text of a Powershell script I'm running, then show some examples (of the same script).

**The code:**

```
<#
.EXAMPLE
How to run the script goes here:
#>
Get-Help $PSCommandPath
Get-Help $PSCommandPath -Examples
```

**Actual output:**

This is just twice the normal help

```
NAME
    D:\GODS\scripts\test.ps1

SYNOPSIS


SYNTAX
    D:\GODS\scripts\test.ps1 [<CommonParameters>]


DESCRIPTION


RELATED LINKS

REMARKS
    To see the examples, type: "Get-Help D:\GODS\scripts\test.ps1 -Examples"
    For more information, type: "Get-Help D:\GODS\scripts\test.ps1 -Detailed"
    For technical information, type: "Get-Help D:\GODS\scripts\test.ps1 -Full"

NAME
    D:\GODS\scripts\test.ps1

SYNOPSIS


SYNTAX
    D:\GODS\scripts\test.ps1 [<CommonParameters>]


DESCRIPTION


RELATED LINKS

REMARKS
    To see the examples, type: "Get-Help D:\GODS\scripts\test.ps1 -Examples"
    For more information, type: "Get-Help D:\GODS\scripts\test.ps1 -Detailed"
    For technical information, type: "Get-Help D:\GODS\scripts\test.ps1 -Full"
```

**Expected output:**

```
NAME
    D:\GODS\scripts\test.ps1

SYNOPSIS


SYNTAX
    D:\GODS\scripts\test.ps1 [<CommonParameters>]


DESCRIPTION


RELATED LINKS

REMARKS
    To see the examples, type: "Get-Help D:\GODS\scripts\test.ps1 -Examples"
    For more information, type: "Get-Help D:\GODS\scripts\test.ps1 -Detailed"
    For technical information, type: "Get-Help D:\GODS\scripts\test.ps1 -Full"

NAME
    D:\GODS\scripts\test.ps1

SYNOPSIS


    -------------------------- EXAMPLE 1 --------------------------

    PS > How to run the script goes here:
```

Comment: For real fun, try reversing these statements. The formatting of the full help will get borked up. I think you've discovered a curiosity of how rendering the help object proceeds. Adding `| Out-Host` to both statements (removing the results from the pipeline) fixes this, for some values of "fixes". Arguably, though, just don't do this sort of thing from within the script itself; it's not a PowerShell convention. Cmdlets normally prompt for arguments when they're needed and it's up to the end user to `Get-Help` when they want to.

Comment: "Cmdlets normally prompt for arguments". I'm aware I'm breaking convention here, but I want to show help (including the examples, which is what beginners would probably want, because that's what **I** would want) if the user does not pass any arguments. I hate it when a script (or program, for that matter) spews out a bunch of manual nonsense that doesn't help me as a beginner. Once I know the basics I can figure out how and what to search - I just want scripts to initially help beginners. Again: Because that's what I'd want :)

Comment: Well, the simplest workaround (`| Out-Host`, or `Write-Host`) is probably also the most appropriate one in that case, since you almost certainly never want the cmdlet's help object to become part of the output pipeline. On the other hand, using host output does prevent help output from being redirected to a file, so yeah. (But you could still write an explicit `Get-Help` for that, so all is not lost.)

Comment: If you add this as an answer, I'll accept it (as it seems to do what I want to do)